# Using LOAD DATA INFILE in perl to insert values in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, perl

I am trying to upload CSV file in to a mysql database using perl. My perl script will reside on a server, which I will access through my browser. In the browser, there will be an option to upload a file.

Question is, how exactly I am gonna do this

1. Do I need to save that file somewhere on the server and then use it ?
2. Can I directly use the file from my laptop by giving a fixed path ?

so far I tried doing this

```
if($update eq "fullLoad"){
$filename =  param("customPricing");


my $upload_filehandle = upload("customPricing"); 
open ( UPLOADFILE, ">$filename" ) or die "$!"; 

binmode UPLOADFILE; 
while ( <$upload_filehandle> )
{
    print UPLOADFILE; 
} 
close UPLOADFILE; 


$query = "LOAD DATA INFILE '\bigmac\bm_src\html\cgi-bin\testbrocade\$filename' INTO TABLE customPricingTest FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','";
$sth = $dbh->do($query) or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n"; 

print $sth . "Records Uploaded <br/>";
```

}

Edited --> Above code is throwing error Access Denied for user . I am successfully able to create the file on the server but looks like I am getting error accessing it..Any ideas ?

Thanks,
Nitesh

Answer (score 1):

In answer to question 1: if you're using `LOAD DATA INFILE`, yes, the file needs to be accessible to the server system and database user. If you use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`, the file can stay on a separate system, run by the Perl script, and data is uploaded in the network connection. There are permissions and settings differences between the two, but performance is very good either way, and we didn't see a huge difference whether loading the data locally or remotely.

For the second question, this is what `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` is for. Here, because the file is read and passed through the DBI connection, the file path needs to be relative to where the script is being run. It doesn't need to be absolute in the way that it would for `LOAD DATA INFILE`. It doesn't even need to be a fixed path. We've used temporary files for this purpose successfully, so long as the files are not deleted until after you have disconnected from the database.

Comment: Thanks for the response...so for LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE I can do something like this LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/folder/tmp/test.txt' INTO TABLE test FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';

Comment: Yes, that will work fine -- so long as your server is configured to allow it, and that is usually the default. If you get an error back "The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version" you might need to modify the MySQL configuration to allow it.

Comment: That worked just fine...I need to generate that path dynamically based on where user is uploading from. I used $filename =  param("customPricing"); AND then $filename as the path of the file but that contains only file name, browser stripped off the path..is there any way I can keep that path?

Comment: You need to do it a little differently. Don't use param() directly, as the browser may lie. Pass the result from param into tmpFileName() to get the real file name. See the CGI documentation at http://search.cpan.org/dist/CGI/lib/CGI.pm#PROCESSING_A_FILE_UPLOAD_FIELD for more info.

Comment: I tried that its '$filename =  param("customPricing");
 $filePath = tmpFileName($filename);' but it throws error saying Undefined subroutine &main::tmpFileName

Comment: Hmmm, that may not be exported by default. It is documented at: http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html#PROCESSING-A-FILE-UPLOAD-FIELD. When you do `use CGI;` you should include the tag `use CGI qw(:form);`, or at least add `:form` to the tags you're using

Comment: haa..that worked !!...thanks but now I guess I am having issues with backward slashes...how can I convert them to forward ? I tried $tmfile = ~ tr/\//\/c; but that's throwing errors

Comment: tr is best avoided a lot of the time, but here it looks like you're escaping is wrong. I'd do `s{\\}{/}g`-- using braces for this helps reduce the leaning toothpick syndrome and makes it more readable

Comment: looks like I am doing something wrong...                        '$filename =  param("customPricing");
 $tmfile = tmpFileName($filename);
 $tmfile = ~ s{\\}{/}g;' ..after trying this , If I print $tmfile it prints a long number around 15-16 digits...any ideas ?

Comment: @morungos let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2165/discussion-between-nitesh-and-morungos)

Comment: even if I hard code the path to a particular file, it throws error File 'C:/Users/nhissaria/Desktop/IncrementalUpload.csv' not found